# Spell Check for Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: spell-check, internet-explorer-9

I just switched to from Chrome to IE9, but there is no built-in spell-checker in IE9...

This is a realy pitty. Is there someone out there that know an addon that works for that?

Comment: I have to agree that real-time spell check is important. In fact, it's the only think keeping me tied to Safari. I just can't believe that Microsoft doesn't see this as an important feature. 

Shame. 

I'll take a look at this program at speckie.com. I'm willing to pay for it, but not much given that I already have it in Safari. I'm not willing to pay $20 to use IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [ieSpell](http://www.iespell.com/).
Also see this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20113/add-spell-checking-to-internet-explorer/)

You might also want consider switching back to Chrome :-)

Comment: The idea here is to use IE for 30 days trial and see if I survive this :) If not, back to Chrome...

Comment: Humm, it's not as you type, is it?

Comment: @Philippe: nope. thats why the back to chrome option ;-)

Comment: @Nivas: oh my god, this is such a show stopper... I can't believe this!

Comment: @Philippe, if your "trial" is still on, you might want to try this: speckie.com/home Looks like what you wanted, a "real time spell checker for IE". – Nivas

Comment: @Nivas: I got back to Chrome since (sadly enough, IE9 is slower than Chrome). But I'm willing to give it a try, still. We'll see, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

[speckie](http://www.speckie.com/home/) - it works with IE9, I've been really happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [iespell](http://www.iespell.com/) , people [claim](http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/113910-why-there-no-spell-checker-ie9.html) it works , dont have ie9 so cannot vouch for it .